# Netlify API Subdomain Connected to DigitalOcean Droplet

Tags: digital-ocean, netlify

I currently have the frontend of my web application running on a Google domain hosted via Netlify. I would like to also host the backend portion of my application on the same site, but different subdomain (eg. [www.webapp.com](http://www.webapp.com) (client) && api.webapp.com (server)). I am currently trying to connect the api.webapp.com Netlify subdomain with my backend on Digital Ocean (Nginx reverse proxy) but am having trouble getting my droplet to connect to the api subdomain. Is this even possible? Would appreciate any insight, thanks!

Currently trying to get certbot (Let's Encrpyt) to certify my server but I think I'm getting an error because by api site is not a www.

```
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: nginx). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: api.webapp.com
  Type:   dns
  Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for api.webapp.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain; DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up AAAA for api.webapp.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain
```